# Cocoa NSAlert does not show alert as sheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, storyboard, nsalert

I have the following code which expects to show alert as sheet in AppDelegate.m.

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {

    if ([self.socket.inputStream streamStatus] == 2) {

        NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        NSWindowController *mainWindowController = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainWindow"];

        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
        [alert setMessageText:NSLocalizedString(@"Warning", @"Warning")];
        [alert setInformativeText:NSLocalizedString(@"Disconnect before quit this app!!", @"Disconnet before quit")];
        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:mainWindowController.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {

        }];

        return NO;

    } else {

        return YES;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, the result alert does not shown as sheet.  Like the screenshot.

[image: doesNotShowAlertAsSheet]

I can't understand why.  And would like to know how can I show alert as sheet.  Please help me!!

Comment: How do you check that it's not a sheet?

Comment: Is the main window already on the screen? Use this main window instead of a new one which isn't visible yet. `instantiateControllerWithIdentifier`: "This method creates a new instance of the specified controller each time you call it."

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for your comment.  I use `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow]` instead of `instantiateControllerWithIdentifier`.  Then the issue was solved!!  Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**It worked for me. I don't know much about.**

May be it is because of the part `beginSheetModalForWindow:`

In your question, it seems that `beginSheetModalForWindow:mainWindowController.window`

I changed it from `mainWindowController.window` to `self.view.window` and it worked, as it is given below:

```
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode)
{
    ....
}];
```

May be it will help i think.